# Fix overlapping dates in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset that looks like this with overlapping dates in Date1 and Date2

```
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Key4 | Value |   Date1    |   Date2    |
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    10 | 2022-01-01 | 2026-01-30 |
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    12 | 2022-06-05 | 2026-01-10 |
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    14 | 2022-08-07 | 2026-01-15 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I want to fix the overlaps and make the dates continuous like this below -

```
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Key4 | Value |   Date1    |   Date2    |
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-06-04 |
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    12 | 2022-06-05 | 2022-08-06 |
| k1   | k2   | k3   | k4   |    14 | 2022-08-07 | 2026-01-15 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

In a sense that, new_date2 = old_date1 (next record) - 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lead](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#lead) Window Function.

```
df = df.withColumn('date2', F.expr('nvl(date_sub(lead(date1) over (order by date1), 1), date2)'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```